# How do I convert this string to an array?

Tags: python, arrays

The string has all the formatting of an array:

```
myString="['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']"
```

I want to make this an array. How would I do that in python?

Comment: You can use the eval() function, even if it's a bit dangerous.
ast.literal_eval, is better, since it won't execute functions.

Comment: @Kavli Nothing wrong with using `eval` or `exec` *if the source is trusted*. For small toy projects where you're the only one entering input, it's safe to assume the source is trusted. `collections.namedtuple` uses `exec` to build its classes. However, it does establish that it's arguments are valid identifiers and so the `exec` will work only as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `literal_eval` (which is safer than `eval`), or you can treat it as a json string:

```
from ast import literal_eval

li = literal_eval("['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']")

# or with the json module

import json
li = json.loads("['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']")
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a hobby project, you can use `eval()` if you want to ensure that it is in fact an array:

```
string = ['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU']
string = eval( string )
```

If you want something more secure, you can use `literal_eval` which won't execute functions.